# Set up running e2e tests using Expo and Appium

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, appium, wdio

I have started to work with Appium a few days ago. Could you, please, help with next moment:

I am using stack Appium + WebdriverIO + Mocha to run tests on real iOS devices.
My developers team uses Expo framework to build React Native mobile app.
Please, advise is it possible to set up integration of Appium + Expo for run tests on real devices?

I have tried to launch tests on real iOS devices using appium capabilities, but I have got an error that code signing procedure has been failed. I did not know what to do with it.